# Custom authentication with django admin with md5 encryption

Tags: python, django, md5, django-authentication, password-hash

I am trying to Custom authentication login with a [legacy database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169607/django-login-with-a-legacy-database-useraccount-table-and-password-table). So far I still do not know how to do it. However, when I copy [this example code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example), and try to write some sample code it can work. However, my legacy database is md5 encryption. I now am trying to change my sample code to md5 encryption.
I just

```
import hashlib
```

and #out

```
ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
```

and in

```
class UserChangeForm:
```

change the code

```
password = hashlib.md5()
```

admin.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
#from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
import hashlib    
from .models import MyUser


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email', 'date_of_birth')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    #password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()
    password = hashlib.md5()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'date_of_birth', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'date_of_birth', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('date_of_birth',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'date_of_birth', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register(MyUser, UserAdmin)
# ... and, since we're not using Django's built-in permissions,
# unregister the Group model from admin.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

however,,when I recreate a user and check my db it is still shows pbkdf2 ??,,

[image]

Can any one tell me how to change to md5? Thank you very much!

Comment: [This isn't encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).

Comment: I recommend you use strong password hashing (e.g. bcrypt) and just expire all current users' passwords. MD5 should never be used to hash passwords.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what you do in your view. The password will still be hashed according to the settings in [`PASSWORD_HASHERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-PASSWORD_HASHERS). I'm not understanding at all why you need to downgrade to MD5...But if you really need to, you can change this setting in *settings.py*:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.UnsaltedSHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.UnsaltedMD5PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
]
```

Comment: I have to use a legacy database,,and the password data all are md5,,so I just trying to hashed the password to  md5,,,.thanks for you to reply